# How to bind value to attribute if this value will changes in each?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I try to do it like that:

```
{{#each item in controller.records}}
  <li {{bind-attr class=":message (compare controller.currentUser.id item.user_id)::mes-self" >
   .....
  </li>
{{/each}}
```

And `mes-self` didn't add to class attribute. Is there possibility to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I see 3 problems in your code:

1. You're using old `{{each in}}` helper. It's deprecated now.
2. You're using deprecated `{{bind-attr}}` helper.
3. You're using shorthand helper with `{{bind-attr}}` + `::` and that's unlikely to work.

Instead, please try:

```
{{#each controller.records key='id' as |item|}}
  <li class="message {{if (compare controller.currentUser.id item.user_id) '' 'mes-self'}}">
   .....
  </li>
{{/each}}
```

I'm assuming you're using Ember v1.13+ and `{{compare}}` expression was declared(you've created this helper) and it returns `true` if passed values are the same.